# Xeround - Connecting to Database with PHP

Tags: php, database, connection, cloud, xeround

I am having issues connecting to my Xeround database through php. I have successfully connected using JDBC in java, but I'm trying to do it from my website and it is not working.

Here is the php code, it's pretty simple.

```
<?php
  $con = mysql_connect("DATABASE INSTANCE","USERNAME","PASSWORD");
  if(!$con) {
  die ('Could not connect to mysql' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("DATABASE TABLE", $con);
?>
```

The error I get when trying to connect says:

```
Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Access denied for user
'USERNAME'@'192.168.1.1' (using password: YES) in     /www/zymichost.com/s/f/x/sfxol/htdocs/db_connect2.php on line 15
Could not connect to mysqlAccess denied for user 'USERNAME'@'192.168.1.1' (using password: YES)
```

Does anyone know what this could be? Is it impossible to connect to Xeround using php? If so, does anyone know another database that is hosted free online that allows remote connections?

All help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use `mysql_connect`, its deprecated. Try `PDO` instead: php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php

Also, on Xeround website, there is a tutorial with `PDO` and `mysqli` extensions:

http://xeround.com/developers/connecting-your-mysql-application-to-xeround-cloud-database/

Comment: Ok, looking at the link you gave me, it doesnt seem easy to use lol, guess I'll have to figure it out (what i need to install etc).

Comment: You have to enable the PHP PDO module and basically thats it.

Comment: Yeah, looks like zymic didn't support it, I found a different way to do what i needed. thanks though!